# Embedded glassfish configuration with Arquillian - TmpDir

Tags: configuration, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

The project:
I am using Arquillian 1.0.0.4-ALPHA with Embedded Glassfish 3.1-b28. My project has an arquillian.xml, NO domain.xml, a sun-resources.xml for my datasource and a persistence.xml. I am trying to unit test an EJB3 / JPA2 application.

What i already did:
My first unit tests even worked. But as soon as I started to develop more than one class using the @Deployment annotation and the static method that returns the webArchive, an exception was thrown. Reason was, that the war file from the first class wasn't correctly undeployed and so the next test file couldn't get deployed. I read about this being a bug and upgraded to a newer version of glassfish to solve the bug.

The problem:
Now the newer version of glassfish leads to a configuration problem. I could fix this by setting the tmpDir in glassfish like mentioned in here:

http://java.net/jira/browse/EMBEDDED_GLASSFISH-122

The question is now, HOW / WHERE can i set those settings? arquillian.xml doesn't seem to be right. And I don't want to use a domain.xml for that case. Best would be sun-resources.xml, but that doesn't seem to fit, too. asadmin doesn't make sense because its a unit test that runs automatically. Can anyone tell me how to configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct entry in arquillian.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.com/arquillian"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:gfembed="urn:arq:org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3">
    <gfembed:container>
        ...
        <gfembed:instanceRoot>\tmp</gfembed:instanceRoot>
    </gfembed:container>
</arquillian>
```